# How to get the return value from pynput.keyboard.Listener Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, return, threadpool, pynput

I would like to get the return value of a function within `pynput.keyboard.Listener`. The only thing I thought it could work was using global variables. Also `ThreadPool`, but I think it will not work in this predefine threading.thread from pynput called keyboard.Listener()

**SAMPLE CODE**

```py
message = ' '
keys = []

def write_keys(keys):
    global message
    for key in keys:
        k = str(key).replace(f'{chr(39)}', '')
        print(k)
        message += k
    if len(message) == 10:
        return message # return this value

def on_press(key):
    global keys
    keys.append(key)
    write_keys(keys)
    keys = []

keyboard_thread = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
keyboard_thread.start()
#messages = return the message value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using `global` variable.You could use ThreadQueue.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from queue import Queue

message = ''
keys = []

queue = Queue()

def write_keys(keys):
    global message
    for key in keys:
        k = str(key).replace(f'{chr(39)}', '')
        print(k)
        message += k
    if len(message) == 10:
        queue.put(message)

def on_press(key):
    global keys
    keys.append(key)
    write_keys(keys)
    keys = []

keyboard_thread = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
keyboard_thread.start()
while True:
    messages = queue.get()
    print(messages)
```

Comment: it works! why this is better than using global variables?

Comment: @Y4RD13 Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I already knew  that, but my question what why is not evil using queues in this way?

Comment: @Y4RD13 No no no, you could see the accepted answer.`"However, sane use of global state is acceptable (as is local state and mutability) even in functional programming, either for algorithm optimization, reduced complexity, caching and memoization, or the practicality of porting structures originating in a predominantly imperative codebase."`.    `Queue.get` would block your code, so it is thread-safe.Whatever, you could use global variable under your circumstance. I just mentioned about thread queue.